# Setting an array value to null

Tags: java, arrays, null

I am trying to change a value of an array to null.

I have an array called card[100].
In this array I have I have 100 cards stored. Each card hold two int values and a string value:

```
public Card(int manaCost, int damageDone, java.lang.String name) {
```

Every array index has been filled but I would like to be able to set a value to null when another method is called. I have tried the following:

1. `array[index] = null;` - this causes an error
2. `array[index] = new array(null, null, null);`
3. A`rray tempArray = null; array[index] = tempArray;`

I am completely baffled as to how to set an array item to null when I feel like this should be an easy fix.

Here is the full code of this class, the method that I am struggling with is **getRandomCard**:

```
public class Deck {

    private Card[] card = new Card[100];
    private int cardsRunning = 100;
    static int DECKSIZE = 100;
    static java.lang.String emailID = "MITNY013";
    private boolean random = false;

    /**
     * Constructor for the Deck. Adds the following cards to the deck in the following order
     * 4x Super Lucky Strike, Damage 100, Mana 2 
     * 6x Mega Santa Hit, Damage 80, Mana 2
     * 10x Critical Hit, Damage 50, Mana 5
     * 10x Massive Strike, Damage 40, Mana 7
     * 15x Wrong Way Down A One Way Street, Damage 30, Mana 10
     * 15x Bender Rules Here, Damage 15, Mana 10
     * 40x Trade, Damage 5, Mana 5 <br>
     * My solution length: 32 lines (space lines not included)
     * @param random - Whether to turn on random features
     */

    public Deck(boolean random) {
        if (random == false) {
            for (int index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card( 2, 100, "Lucky Strike");}
            for (int index = 4; index <= 10; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card( 2, 80, "Santa Hit");}
            for (int index = 11; index <= 20; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card( 5, 50, "Critical Hit");}
            for (int index = 21; index <= 30; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card ( 7, 40, "Massive Strike");}
            for (int index = 31; index <= 45; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card( 10, 30, "Wrong Way Down A One Way Street");}
            for (int index = 46; index <= 60; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card( 10, 15, "Bender Rules Here");} 
            for (int index = 61; index <= cardsRunning-1; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card( 5, 5, "Trade");} }
        else if (random == true) { 
            for (int index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card( 2, 100, "Lucky Strike");}
            for (int index = 4; index <= 10; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card( 2, 80, "Santa Hit");}
            for (int index = 11; index <= 20; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card( 5, 50, "Critical Hit");}
            for (int index = 21; index <= 30; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card ( 7, 40, "Massive Strike");}
            for (int index = 31; index <= 45; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card( 10, 30, "Wrong Way Down A One Way Street");}
            for (int index = 46; index <= 60; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card( 10, 15, "Bender Rules Here");} 
            for (int index = 61; index <= cardsRunning-1; index++) {
                card[index] = new Card( 5, 5, "Trade");}
            shuffle(card);}
    }


    /**
     * Returns a string representation of the entire deck in the format
     * Deck [ 1:Card [name=Super Lucky Strike, manaCost=2, damageDone=100]
     *        2:Card [name=Super Lucky Strike, manaCost=2, damageDone=100]
     *        3:Card [name=Super Lucky Strike, manaCost=2, damageDone=100]
     *        4:Card [name=Super Lucky Strike, manaCost=2, damageDone=100]] <br>
     * My solution length: 6 lines
     * @overrides - toString in class java.lang.Object
     */

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index = 0; index < card.length; index++) {
            sb.append((index + 1) + ": " +  card[index].toString() + "\n");}
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Uses a random number generator to get a card from the deck somewhere then swaps the 
     * last card in the deck to that position and reduces the cardsRemaining by one. 
     * This is important. if the random flag is false you should always get the card at 
     * position 0. When you swap the card out you should also set the old position to null 
     * for safety. <br>
     * My solution length: 6 lines
     * @return - the card drawn or null if no cards left in deck
     */

    public Card getRandomCard() {
        if (cardsRunning == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        // use random number generator to generate a number to get a card from the deck
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomCardNo = rand.nextInt(cardsRunning);
        // created newCard in order to return the original random card as it will be replaced by the last value 
        //in the partially fill array
        Card newCard = card[randomCardNo]; 
        //reorder the array - swaps the last card in the deck to the position of the card being removed
        card[randomCardNo] = card[cardsRunning-1];
        //Set the card[cardsRunning -1] to null value so it is removed form the deck
        card[cardsRunning-1] = null;
        cardsRunning--;
        return newCard;
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of cards remaining in the deck.
     * My solution length: 1 lines
     * @return - the total cards remaining
     */

    public int getCardsRemaining() {
        return this.cardsRunning;}


    /**
     * BONUS Method
     * My solution length: 6 lines
     */
    public void shuffle(Card[] card) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int index = 0; index < card.length; index++) {
            int randomIndexToSwap = rand.nextInt(card.length);
            Card temp = card[randomIndexToSwap];
            card[randomIndexToSwap] = card[index];
            card[index] = temp;}
    }
```

As mentioned the error is a NullPointerException, but I cam not sure how to convert card[] to a list given it has 3 variables..hmmm

Thanks for your help,

Comment: What error do you get? I´d expect `card[index] = null` to work. Apart from this you shouldn´t create new instances of `Random` again and again. Do it once and only once within your class and use that instance all over.

Comment: What is `Card`?

Comment: I would suggest to use a `List<Card>` instead of an array, as it enables you to dynamically add and remove `Card`-instances. No need to set anything to `null`.

Comment: Instead of guessing what OPs problem may or may not be, can we please close this question until OP clearly states what his/her error is.

Comment: card is public Card(int manaCost, int damageDone, java.lang.String name)

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
card[index]=null;
```

does not throw errors itself. However, it is logical that after this, any attempt at manipulation of the element at that index will start throwing `NullPointerException`.

So, one way to handle this, is to introduce the concept of an empty or missing card. Perhaps by adding a boolean field to your Card class, and then checking that `card[index].isEmpty()==false` before you do anything with that card.

But it might be more appropriate and intuitive if instead you, change the array to an ArrayList where it is easy to completely remove or add an element on demand, like HimBromBeere suggested